# Access List box including information from text box

Tags: forms, ms-access, textbox

currently using Access and would like to add a list box to a form.

Is it possible to add a list box on a form which contains data from a text that is held in another form on the same Access database?

The text box isn't stored as data in my database so struggling as to how I would could do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other form is open, you can dynamically populate the list box.

For example I have two forms.

Form 1 (called Frm1) has 1 textbox, called txtItemList.  I've populated this with "1,2,3,4"

[image]

Form 2 (called Frm2) has 1 listbox, called lst1.  Frm2 has an event on load that populates the listbox with data from Form 1.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.lst1.RowSource = Forms!FRM1.txtitemlist
Me.lst1.RowSourceType = "Value List"
End Sub
```

Now when Form 2 loads, it populates lst1 with values from txtItemListfrom Form 1.
[image]